# Password Reset in Django with rest_auth

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have extended **PasswordResetConfirmSerializer** from rest_auth.views. and the url pattern is mapped as follows.

```
urlpatterns = [
    .
    path('password/reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    .
]
```

The email generates the password reset content which provide the link matching the above pattern.

But this api has fields for :

1. new_password1
2. new_password2
3. uid
4. token

How to pass the uid and token from URL to the post field? Or is there any other method?

Comment: A side comment: `django-rest-auth` is unmanteined (they say "[on pause](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/568)") since September 2019.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Just don’t use that endpoint. Too much JS to be used. Try django-allauth.

Typically for a REST API app, an email confirmation for registration and password reset is expected to be completed on a browser. Disclaimer: I use cookiecutter django which comes with django-allauth, and I used rest-auth’s register and login functionality. I used the password reset link but did not use the confirmation url because using JS in an email to grab the confirmation link’s token and uid and translate it into another request with JS is annoyingly unnecessary. Sp just use django-allauth instead.

I mean... well I suppose if you hacked into rest-auth’s templates and added the uid and token, then you could have the user copy the uid and token into your mobile application and then have the user type his/her new password. But that ruins UX, so just don’t use that endpoint.